# how to tell Linux that certain pins on the board are for SPI/I2C

Tags: linux, i2c, spi

Say I have a custom Linux build which would got on custom chip with a custom board. The chip supports SPI and I2C. How do I tell my Linux build that certain pins on the chip correspond to SPI and certain pins correspond to I2C?

Feel free to move the question to the correct Stack Exchange site. I wasn't sure which one I should be using, so I started here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree

Answer (score 0):

These kind of information are generally passed using a device tree. Please refer [device_tree_tutorial](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1) for more information on device tree.